# How can I see the current POST Request's content?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

Using the current HTTP Context, how can I see the content of the current POST request that has just been posted to the server?

Answer (score 2):

HttpContext.Current.Request.Form is a collection of name value pairs for posted content. I assume this is what you want rather than the raw post data...

Edit to add: My curiosity piqued I decided to go look for the raw post data. It seems there is a .InputStream property on the request object that "Gets the contents of the incoming HTTP entity body". I suspect this will be the raw data.

Comment: Usually this would work, but in this case I am trying to evaluate the request from a WCF web service. The post content is just one xml chunk, no name value pairs.

Comment: @SilverSurfer: Hopefully you saw my updated answer with the .InputSTream property. Does this allow you to do what you want? A bit of a faff having to work with a stream rather than just getting a string but hopefully it will do what you want...

Answer (score 0):

the firebug extension of firefox lets you see exactly what is posted to the server.  not sure if that's helpful to you or not.

Comment: The request is not posted via a browser. It's originating from a third party client program.

Comment: that's probably something you should have mentioned in the question ;)

Comment: Yes, I should have, sorry... BTW: I haven't downvoted your post. Even I would have wanted to, my account wouldn't let me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're speaking from a test/eval perspective.  Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).  Assuming your WCF isnt doing anythign too fancy/non-standard, you can see the content of the request/response bodies.

Now from a code perspective, you'd need to access the Post content and parse through it as has been mentioned

Comment: The request is not posted via a browser. It's originating from a third party client program.

Comment: .NET client services running on windows utilize the Win32 INET api to make their calls, which is what Fiddler analyses. Thats exactly why I recommended it OVER Firebug, which is a browser-only tool. Try the tool next time, before you get all overly zealous with the down-rank :)

Comment: I haven't downvoted your post. I can't even do that with only one point on my account.

Comment: considering the question, this was a good answer. no need for it to be downvoted.  +1 to counter the downvote :)

Comment: interesting.  Sorry for the assumption.  Try Fiddler though, I use it for debugging WCF client<>server interactions